# Azure AD token has already access to other app without permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have 2 apps registered in Azure AD, let's call them WebApi1 and WebApi2.

WebApi1 needs to call WebApi2. A secret has been configured in WebApi1 in order to get a token. Here is the code I'm using to get the token and then make the call to WebApi2:

[image]

And here is how my WebApi2 is configured:

[image]

The thing that I don't understand is that I would expect WebApi2 to return a 401 exception since I have not set any permissions in Azure (via the App Registration portal) to WebApi1.

Yet, the call is made successfully and WebApi1 has access to WebApi2.

Why WebApi1 has access to WebApi2 without the use of permissions in Azure?

Comment: Elferone, what is the value for ``AzureAd:Audiences`` in your config file?

Comment: That config contains 2 application ids: First one is another external app and the second one is the App Id of WebApi2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web api application should check access using the IsInRole() or the [Authorize] attribute. If your web api doesn't check access , by default the access token with no application roles(permission) could access to your web api .

Please refer to document [Roles based access control in cloud applications using Azure AD](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) . Since you are acquiring token with application identity (client credential flow) , please check the `Assigning client applications to application roles of resource APIs` section in the document .

Comment: It is true that we don't use roles yet, but each controller in the api is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute. Are you telling me that all these permissions settings in Azure won't work unless I use roles and validate them in the API?

Comment: Do your [Authorize] attributes check the roles , like Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]  ? If only [Authorize] , it won't check the roles .

Answer (score 0):

Just another thing.

If you're working with Azure and roles, when setting the  WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions, you'll need to set the right role type in order for IsInRole (or Authorize("YourRole")) to work.

```
 app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:Audience"],
                    RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role
                },
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:Tenant"],

            });
```